# Tracking movement from another exe window in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, itunes

I am looking for a way to track the movement (resizing, moving) of another window (in my case iTunes). I am currently developing an iTunes plug-in and I would like to have my WPF plug-in to stick on the iTunes window when dragged, resized, etc. The iTunes COM for Windows SDK offers events on maximize and minimize, unfortunately there are no events for resizing and moving the window. I've also seen people using the `SetParent` on other win32 apps but I don't this will work in my case.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Yes, I have tried the SetParent option but it didn't work for me. I've seen some tutorials on ways to do sticky windows but what I really want is a way to fire an event when the window is moved. In that way, I will be able to adjust my window to make it "stick".